# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type CLASS

Tags: flutter, bloc

in flutter i just learn how can i use `Bloc` on applications and i want to try to implementing simple login with this feature. after implementing some class of `bloc` to using that on view

i get error when i try to use this code as

```
BlocProvider.of<LoginListingBloc>(context).dispatch(LoginEvent(loginInfoModel: testLogin));
```

inside `RaisedButton`

**Error:**

> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc
>   of type  LoginListingBloc.

My view :

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  LoginListingBloc _loginListingBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loginListingBloc =
        LoginListingBloc(loginRepository: widget.loginRepository);
  }

  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: _loginListingBloc,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 5.0, title: Text('Sample Code', style: appBarTextStyle)),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'click here',
                style: defaultButtonStyle,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                BlocProvider.of<LoginListingBloc>(context).dispatch(LoginEvent(loginInfoModel: testLogin));
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`LoginListingBloc` class:

```
class LoginListingBloc extends Bloc<LoginListingEvent, LoginListingStates> {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;

  LoginListingBloc({this.loginRepository});

  @override
  LoginListingStates get initialState => LoginUninitializedState();

  @override
  Stream<LoginListingStates> mapEventToState(
      LoginListingStates currentState, LoginListingEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginEvent) {
      yield LoginFetchingState();
      try {
        final loginInfo = await loginRepository.fetchLoginToPage(
            event.loginInfoModel.username, event.loginInfoModel.password);
        yield LoginFetchedState(userInfo: loginInfo);
      } catch (_) {
        yield LoginErrorState();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and other classes if you want to see theme

`AppApiProvider` class:

```
class AppApiProvider {
  final successCode = 200;

  Future<UserInfo> fetchLoginToPage(String username, String password) async {
    final response = await http.get(Constants.url + "/api/v1/getPersons");
    final responseString = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == successCode) {
      print(responseString);
      return UserInfo.fromJson(responseString);
    } else {
      throw Exception('failed to get information');
    }
  }
}
```

`LoginEvent`:

```
class LoginEvent extends LoginListingEvent {
  final LoginInfoModel loginInfoModel;

  LoginEvent({@required this.loginInfoModel}) : assert(loginInfoModel != null);
}
```

`LoginInfoModel`:

```
class LoginInfoModel {
  String username;
  String password;

  LoginInfoModel({this.username, this.password});
}

final testLogin = LoginInfoModel(username:'exmaple',password:'text');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to access loginListingBloc from `context` since it exists in the current class and not up the widget tree.

change:

```
BlocProvider.of<LoginListingBloc>(context).dispatch(LoginEvent(loginInfoModel: testLogin));
```

to:

```
_loginListingBloc.dispatch(LoginEvent(loginInfoModel: testLogin));
```

Comment: could you help me on this topic? `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207806/1830228` thanks

Comment: The whole idea of the BLoC pattern is to separate UI from business logic.
If the BLoC is instantiated inside the widget, there is no possibility of mocking it in a widget test. I highly discourage one from doing it like that. The dependencies should be **injected into the widget** not the other way around!

Answer (score 6):

For all others who come here for the error message: 
Make sure you always specify the types and don't omit them:

```
BlocProvider<YourBloc>(
    create: (context) => YourBloc()
    child: YourWidget()
);
```

and also for

```
BlocProvider.of<YourBloc>(context);
```