# Flutter simple implementation to handle click event with Bloc work once

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I just learn about how can i use `Bloc` in flutter applications and my simple app i have some separated view class as `App` and `MainPage` and i implemented simple `Bloc` pattern to handle click event on some widgets such as button

after running application my implemented bloc pattern only work once and show message in console and after click again that don't work to show message

my `main.dart` class

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: Strings.appName,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
    ),
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  final HomeBloc homeBloc = HomeBloc();

  @override
  State<App> createState() => MainPage();
}
```

`MainPage` class:

```
class MainPage extends State<App> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  HomeBloc get _homeBloc => widget.homeBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: Strings.appName,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: BlocBuilder<HomeEvent,HomeState>(
          bloc: _homeBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context, HomeState state) {
            if (state is HandleDrawerMenuClick) {
              _onWidgetDidBuild(() {
                print("clicked on drawer menu");
              });
            }

            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('ddddddddd'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _homeBloc.dispatch(OnDrawerMenuClicked());
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _homeBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onWidgetDidBuild(Function callback) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      callback();
    });
  }
}
```

`HomeBloc` class:

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  @override
  HomeState get initialState => HomeState();

  @override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(HomeEvent event) async* {
    if (event is OnDrawerMenuClicked) {
      yield HandleDrawerMenuClick();
    }
  }
}
```

`HomeEvent` class:

```
class HomeEvent extends Equatable {
  HomeEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class OnDrawerMenuClicked extends HomeEvent {
  OnDrawerMenuClicked() : super([]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'OnDrawerMenuClicked clicked';
}
```

`HomeState` class:

```
class HomeState extends Equatable{
  HomeState([List props = const[]]):super(props);
}

class HandleDrawerMenuClick extends HomeState{
  @override
  String toString()=>'HandleDrawerMenuClick';
}
```

i think problem is on `HandleDrawerMenuClick` class because when i debug application, debug can go into `if` statement on this line:

```
if (event is OnDrawerMenuClicked) {
  yield HandleDrawerMenuClick();
}
```

and i think twice click on button couldn't trigger `yield HandleDrawerMenuClick();`

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproduction of this problem?

Comment: @HugoPassos yes sure, please let me to create

Comment: You don't need event-state for this primitive functionality. It's clearly an overkill. First try to comprehend BLoC without event-state. Later when start to create real reactive applications you'll understand why event-state is useful and how to use it.

Comment: @mathronaut maybe you have right, that is simple implementation for using some feature in Bloc

Comment: can't find the issue :-(

Comment: @nonybrighto reference: `https://github.com/felangel/`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an intended behavior because blocs doesn't re-emit on the same state as mentioned on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2288#issuecomment-812330576).